# How to use AWS Shield Standard properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

Do i have to configure AWS Shield Standard?

I want to protect the infrastructure with the best practices offered by aws so i configure some services like cloudfront or beanstalk, Api gateway for default their tool are using aws shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. As documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/getting-started/), it's automatically enabled in your account.

Comment: by last, do I need advanced aws shield for API gateway access and integration?

Comment: I would say no, since API Gateway isn't even listed as one of the services covered by Shield Advanced.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a website you can 'actively' use Shield Standard by using CloudFront for website delivery and Route53 for DNS which both have 'always-on' mitigations in place for L3/4 attacks.

Also for websites use AWS WAF with rate-based rule(s) in 'Block' mode for L7 DDoS protection and please for the love of god - enable **caching** on CloudFront for static resources.  Design your website so that the pages,  (especially '/' URI [1]) is cacheable.

Also with AWS WAF use the Amazon Managed Rule-groups [2] esp the IP Reputation and Anonymous lists (although beware the Hosting provider list - it will block clients using non-AWS based SaaS network egress providers).

If you have a non-web application use Global Accelerator (and R53) for the best Shield standard protection.

[1] '/' is the most commonly attacked URI for Request Flood DDoS attacks

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/aws-managed-rule-groups-ip-rep.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS Shield standard is enabled by default for all AWS Resources and Accounts. You don't have to do anything for that. But shield standard gives only limited protection only compared to shield advanced subscription.

Read more about standard and advanced shield.

https://aws.amazon.com/shield/features/